# Editing files via user interface in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have SSH access to an Ubuntu server. Now I'd like to edit the files in some folder like

```
/home/test
```

Is there any way that I can get an editor like Dreamweaver which can ssh to Ubuntu and files in that folder open up like FTP and I can edit and save them?

Comment: Your approach is asking for trouble. Dreamweaver makes me assume you want to edit live content of a web site. Don't do that. Make a difference between the stable version that goes live and development version. Use a source code management system that will allow you to undo things easily if you screw up something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better, since you have SSH access you most likely be able to use SFTP, which means you should be able to mount your home directory on the server server locally. That way you can directly edit the files on the server as if they were files on your local hard drive, kind of.

Since you are talking about Dreamweaver I assume you are running Windows on your desktop computer? In that case you might want to take a look at [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows), which will give you a remote SFTP connection mounted as a drive letter.

Comment: thanks buddy that worked , but how can i loo with root account , because on terminal i have to use sudo and then edit the file and save it.
how should i do it now

Comment: First of all, are you sure you need to mount using the root account? Another option might be to change the ownership of the folders you need to edit. That said, if you still need root login you can a) sudo password root b) place a ssh key inside /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinSCP or FileZilla to access the file via SCP (and also maybe SFTP). You download the file on your machine then you can edit it with any editor your heart desires. Once you're done, all you have to do is upload it back onto the server.

On a side note, you should consider learning how to use VIM which is the standard for Unix text editing.

Comment: No, scp and sftp is not the same thing.

Comment: Indeed, but if one works, the other one will most likely work =)